# Trying to find projection transformation matrix using basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the basis $[1, 0]^T$ and $[0, 1]^T$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I am trying to understand their projection onto the $\theta$-line. According to a text I am reading:

> The length of the projection is $c=cos\theta$. Notice that the point of projection is not $[c, s]^T$, as I mistakenly thought; that vector has length 1 (it is the rotation), so we multiply by $c$. Similarly, the projection of $[0, 1]^T$ has length $s$, and falls as $s[c, s]^T=[cs, s^2]^T$.

I can see that the point $[c, s]^T$ is the rotated point $[1, 0]^T$ and the length of the vector $[c, s]^T$ is one but why should we multiply with  $c$ to get the real projection point? The same query holds for $[0,1]^T$.

Thanks!

Comment: The projection of $\bf x$ onto the line spanned by the unit vector $\bf u$ is $({\bf x} \cdot {\bf u}) {\bf u}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point $(c,s)$ is on the given line, so is the projection $\bf p$, therefore
$${\bf p}=\lambda(c,s)$$
for some scalar $\lambda$.  As noted in your question, $(c,s)$ has length $1$ and $\bf p$ has length $c$ (if you are not clear on this, draw a diagram), therefore $\lambda=c$.